# Laravel Routing Post method failed

Tags: php, laravel, post, router

This is my html form; 
`<form action="{{url('admin/users/update/'.$user->id)}}" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            {{method_field('put')}}`

and this is my router;
`Route::post('users/update/{id}', 'UsersController@update');`

and this is my controller

```
 public function update($id)
{
    //$id=$_POST['id'];
    $user = \App\User::find($id);
    $user->email = $_POST['email'];
    $user->name = $_POST['name'];
    if ($_POST['password'] != '') {
        $user->password = Hash::make($_POST['password']);

    }
    $user->user_level = $_POST['user_level'];
    $user->location =$_POST['location'];
    $user->gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $user->save();
```

My code doesn't work. How can I fix it? The error is 
Symphony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException No Message

Comment: Your form points to `admin/users/update/`, your route is `users/update/` though

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html). Your route is wrong, update need to use the request object, use Form::open and route name.

Comment: No. It's not wrong.

Comment: @MustafaUYSAL It is. You can't use `url` to define in form and your missing the `admin/`

Comment: Why i cant't use url???

Comment: @MustafaUYSALl It's not you can't use it, but it's a bad practise. If you change you route you will need more update in your files. It's why you should use route with a name. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#generating-basic-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove **{{method_field ('put')}}**. Because this code means that your form is being sent via put method and there is no put in the router.

Solution 1. Delete **{{method_field ('put')}}**.

Solution 2. Change the router definition to:

```
Route::put('users/update/{id}', 'UsersController@update');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Route**:

```
Route::post('users/update/{id}', 'UsersController@update')->name('user.update);
```

**Form**:

```
<form action="{{['route' => ['user.update', $user->id]}}" method="post">
```

Comment: @MustafaUYSAL But it's the correct way to it. What's not working ?

Comment: When i rewrite use your code, the error is:htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mustafa\local\resources\views\admin\pages\users\edit.blade.php)

Comment: @MustafaUYSAL Like the error said it's a problem in your view file `edit.blade.php` with `htmlspechialchars()` so it's not a route problem.

Comment: i can't see edit page when i use this. but before this i can see edit page.

Comment: @MustafaUYSAL: Please provide your edit.blade.php and route code with my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTTP request via dependency injection

Declare first the Illuminate\Http\Request class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //$id=$_POST['id'];
    $user = \App\User::find($id);
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    if ($request->input('password') != '') {
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

    }
    $user->user_level =$request->input('userlevel');
    $user->location =$request->input('location');
    $user->gender = $request->input('gender');
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: It is still same

Answer (score 0):

Did you use below code into your form:

```
{!! Form::token() !!}
```

or you can try use "put" instead of "get"

Comment: Yes i use this.

Answer (score 0):

did you declare @csrf in the form.

```
    use App\User;
      use Auth;
      use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

         public function update(Request $r,$id)
        {
            //$id=$_POST['id'];
            $user = User::find($id); // if auth is necessary  $user = Auth::id();
            $user->update([

          'email' => $r->email,
          'name' => $r->name,
          'password' => Hash::make($r['password']),
          'user_level' => $r->user_level,
          'location'=> $r->location,
          'gender'  => $r->gender


    ]);     
}
```

in your web.php

```
Route::post('/user/update/{id}', [
  'uses' => 'UsersController@update',
  'as' => 'user.store'
]);
```

in your form

```
<form class="" action="{{route('user.store')}}" method="post">
  @csrf
```

Comment: Yes i declare it but i don't write it here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should install Laravel Collection it helps in adding some token to the form 
Check out this documentation here https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html
Please notify me if it works.